# SharePoint 2013 not crawling PDFs designed in LiveCycle

Tags: search, pdf, crawl

In SharePoint 2013 I am getting **"Processing this item failed because of a PDF parser error"** search crawl error for all my PDF forms which were created using Adobe LiveCycle Designer. The error says

> "Document is not a valid PDF document"

Is this a known problem with these types of PDFs?

Is there a way around it?

Comment: Did you solve your problem, i'm getting the same issue.
Thanks
dimitri

Comment: Unfortunately this is still a problem for us, Dimitri.